# A conjecture on energy distribution of product states in locally interacting systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, wavefunction, mathematical-physics

Let $\hat{H}$ be a locally-interacting quantum many body Hamiltonian, for example the nearest-neighbor interacting [quantum Heisenberg model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_(quantum)) or [Hubbard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard_model), and let $|\psi \rangle$ be an arbitrary product state (normalized). Let $|E \rangle$ be an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$: $\hat{H}|E\rangle=E|E\rangle$.

**Conjecture: There exists a constant $\alpha$ independent of the energy $E$ and the system size, such that $$|\langle E|\psi\rangle|\leq e^{-\alpha|E-E_\psi|},\tag{1}$$
where $E_\psi=\langle\psi|\hat{H}|\psi\rangle$.**

This conjecture is basically saying that *the energy of a product state in a locally-interacting system is distributed in a very narrow window of width $\sim 2/\alpha$ centered around its expectation value $E_\psi$.*

While this conjecture seems reasonable, has it been proved or can someone prove it?

Notice that a may-be-related result appeared [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01474), where the authors proved that under the same conditions mentioned above, for eigenstates $|E_1\rangle,|E_2\rangle$ and local operator $\hat{A}$, the exists constant $\kappa$, such that $$|\langle E_1|\hat{A}|E_2\rangle|\leq e^{-\kappa |E_1-E_2|}.\tag{2}$$
I've got a feeling that Eq.(2) may be used to prove Eq.(1)...but it's just a guess.
Any hints, comments, attempts, or counterexamples if any, are welcomed.

Comment: What your conjecture is essentially saying is that all product states are dominated by the contribution of a small subset of energy eigenstates. However by the same token is says that all energy eigenstates are dominated by the contribution of a small subset of product states. In other words the energy eigenstates are an entangled mixture of not many states.

Comment: Now this does not necessarily imply that the energy eigenstates are not strongly entangled, but it still seems implausible to me; I would expect the highly excited states of a many body system to be an entangled mixture of many possible states. You might be able to say something about the low lying energy states, which obey an area entanglement law, but for a general energy eigenstate, obeying a volume law of entanglement, I would expect it to be false